# REST Server connection reset on Routing path

Tags: c#, rest, routes, path-parameter

Question is: Did I define the client resource call correctly, or is there something wrong in the server code?

I have a REST API server I am coding in C# / Visual Studio 2019 using the Web API template.  I have 2 paths at the moment - a POST and a GET.

POST:  /api/account
GET:   /api/account/{accountid:long}

POST works great using SoapUI as a test client, but GET gives me a connection reset (message is "Error getting response; java.net.SocketException: Connection reset").

I hope I defined the resource correctly:
[image]

Here's my Controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Coda.Core;
using CodaRESTServer.Models;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyRESTServer.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/account")]
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{accountid:long}")]
        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public JObject Get(long accountid)
        {
            var x = new JObject();
            x["worked"] = "true";
            return (x);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        // POST api/account
        public JObject Post()
        {
            var x = new JObject();
            x["worked"] = "true";
            return (x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I specified it wrong in SoapUI.  It needs to be:

`/api/account/{accountid}`

And then I can click on the Parameters field and enter the value.